# Ordinary function pointer to class instance member function

Tags: c++

Is there any way we can use ordinary function pointer to point to class instance member function?

eg.

```
class A;
typedef void (*Callback) (int a);

class A
{
    public :
    void Print(int a)
    {
        std::cout<< a << std::endl;
    }

    Callback GetPrintMethod() //error cannot convert void(*) (int) to void(A::*) (int)
     {
         return &A::Print;
     }
};

int main()
{
    A* a(new A());
    Callback callback = a->GetPrintMethod(); 
    (*callback)(10);
}
```

Comment: Why not ask about your problem, rather than about your perceived solution? (Which is impossible, btw).

Comment: I have third party library which provides callback (an ordinary callback). I have a wrapper which hides this detail ( about the callback from third party) from client . For this, I've provided a function (e.g. std::vector<std::function<void (int)>>  unmanagedCallbacks). I would like to avoid having defined this in static method as I want to call the callback on object that has subscribed this. Otherwise I need to maintain dictionary of object and function pointer .